# JSX does not compile in for loop

Tags: reactjs, jsx

The following code does not compile correctly for me as JSX :

```
  let headerText = "";
  if (objArgs.column.name instanceof Array) {
    headerText = <ul>;
    objArgs.column.name.forEach( (item, idx) => {
        headerText = headerText + <li> +  item + </li>;
        return headerText;
      }
    );
    headerText = headerText + </ul>;
  }
```

I just want to create a list out of an array using JSX. The error says that a bracket is out of place. As soon as I remove the JSX elements it works again. Am I using JSX correctly in this snippet?

Comment: You are trying to concatenate JSX nodes into a string. This ins't valid. I think you want to build up an array of JSX nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate JSX nodes into a string:

```
let headerText = "";
...
headerText = headerText + <li> + item + </li>
```

This is not how JSX works. JSX is not like building an HTML string that gets set with `innerHTML`. Rather it is an object node structure that React will render to HTML, and JSX `< >` syntax is just a declarative way to write function calls that return JSX nodes.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
let headerText;
if (objArgs.column.name instanceof Array) {
  headerText = <ul>
    { objArgs.column.name.map(item => <li>{item}</li>) }
  </ul>;
}
```

Now you can render the whole `headerText` somewhere.

**Notes:**

- `headerText` is `null` (renders empty) or an array of JSX nodes (renders a list).
- You render valid JS values in JSX using `{ value }`, not `+ value +`.
- You can just use `Array.map()` to convert your array to JSX nodes and render them inside another JSX node, like `<ul>{ array.map(...) }</ul>`. This is the common way arrays are rendered to JSX.
- Your `<li>` items [should have a `key`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html), like `<li key={item.id}>`. Using the array [index as key is not a good idea](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318), and using the `item` itself is only a good idea *if every item is unique* (and a primitive value).